# How to use "tens of" and "hundreds of"?

Tags: meaning, numbers

If I'm not mistaken, *tens of* means 10 to 99 and *hundreds of* means 100 to 999. Is this correct? I found in some dictionaries that *tens of* is actually not correct.

I also found that *hundreds of* could also mean any arbitrary large number. So how would people usually interpret *hundreds of*? Based on context?

In my case, I want to describe numbers of some items that are usually 50-90 but sometimes could be around 100-200, but definitely not as many as 300 or so. I want to really emphasize that there are *a lot of* these items. In this case, can I say "... have tens or even hundreds of ..."? Would people misinterpret what I actually want to say?

Comment: Related (more attention, but closed as duplicate): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36975/a-word-like-hundreds-but-for-multiples-of-10

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In English, one would normally say "dozens of" rather than "tens of", so there is some overlap. I might use "dozens of" for an amount between 36 (a dozen, two dozen, dozens...) and 132 (a dozen less than a gross), "scores of" for a number between 40 and 199, and "hundreds of" for values greater than that. I don't think I've ever thought about the reasoning behind this; it would really depend on which number sounded better in the areas which overlap.

Answer (score 10):

As I understand it, the usage is:

**Tens of** -- rarely used; "as many as XX" might be more appropriate

**Hundreds of** -- any number from 100 - 999; "more than 500" might be more appropriate for numbers greater than 500

**Thousands of** -- any number from 1,000 to 9,999

**Tens of Thousands of** -- any number from 10,000 to 99,999

**Hundreds of Thousands of** -- any number from 100,000 to 999,999; after 250,000, it is more appropriate to use quarter, half and three-quarter million

Comment: I wouldn't use *hundreds* for anything less than about 200 - a single hundred doesn't warrant a plural. Similarly for the other words, except *tens of*, which is just wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I have only heard of "tens" used in, "tens of thousands." Otherwise "scores" is used. Scores being 20-199. And "hundreds" is plural so it would be 200-1999.

Answer (score 2):

When describing victims of a disaster, "tens of" usually means less than a hundred or a bit more, and "hundreds of" can mean up to a thousand or a few more.  "Hundreds of dead" could be over a thousand, but the results are still unsure.

"Hundreds of" and "thousands of" are more common than "tens of", but if I heard the statement, I would expect "tens of" to be 30 to about 120 or so.  A more common phrase for the same general amount is "dozens of".

Answer (score 1):

You can use *hundreds of* in sentences like the following.

> It costs hundreds of dollars.
>   An unknown number, probably in the hundreds, had already been lost.
>   Hundreds of letters poured in.

In the last sentence, *hundreds of* is used to mean an unspecified large number.

Similarly, you can use *tens of* (except in sentences like the last one).

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm not mistaken, "*tens of*" means 10 to 99 and "*hundreds of*" means 100
>   to 999. Is this correct? I found in some dictionaries that "*tens of*" is
>   actually not correct.

An unqualified "*tens*" covers the range from "*one ten*" through "*a few tens*" and on to "*many tens*", so you can answer it by asking whether *many* stops at 9.9, which it doesn't. There could quite reasonably be 17 tens, for example.

> I also found that "*hundreds of*" could also mean any arbitrary large
>   number. So how would people usually interpret "*hundreds of*"? Based on
>   context?

Yes, and you might have to conclude that you haven't been given enough information to judge.

> In my case, I want to describe numbers of some items that are usually
>   50-90 but sometimes could be around 100-200, but definitely not as
>   many as 300 or so. I want to really emphasize that there are a lot of
>   these items. In this case, can I say "*... have tens or even hundreds
>   of ...*"? Would people misinterpret what I actually want to say?

If you use "*tens or even hundreds*" then the "*even*" says that hundreds is not the usual case and "*tens or even*" suggests that it's the low hundreds. However "*tens*" can be fewer than fifty and "*hundreds*" could be taken as three hundred or more.

As you **definitely** do not wish to convey the possibility of as
many as three hundred, you'd need to be definite in saying it. The way you put it is fine - "*usually 50-90 but sometimes 100-200*" - or anything similar - "*50-200 but usually less than 100*" or "*fifty to a hundred, maybe a couple of hundred*".