# Why do we not say "tens of"?

Tags: phrases

We say 'hundreds of', 'thousands of', 'millions of', even 'tens of thousands of', but not 'tens of'. The usual expression is 'dozens of'. Does anyone know why?

Comment: We do say 'forties of' however. For example "We drank a few forties of..."

Comment: Usually we say "scores of" to capture multiples of 20.

Comment: Related: [How to use “tens of” and “hundreds of”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16356/how-to-use-tens-of-and-hundreds-of)

Comment: Errr...I find "tens of" fairly common.

Comment: Of the first ten pages of a Google search I ran before posting the question about 90% of the hits were 'tens of thousands', with a few 'tens of millions/billions'. There were only 2 'tens of' (Bush supporters / dollars).

Comment: @ Erc Naslund. Do we? I don't.

Comment: @EricNaslund is making a joke: in the United States, very inexpensive "Malt Liquor" (fortified beer) and beer are sold in forty ounce bottles, often referred to as "forties."  So, "We drank a few forties of Old E[nglish, a brand of beer]." [urban D](http://forty.urbanup.com/202938)

Comment: @BarrieEngland: ...it is a joke, I am referring to slang for alchohol. When you say a forty, it refers to 40 oz, which is a possible size for a bottle of liquor.  There is the connotation of drinking just to get drunk, and it is almost never used to refer to high class alcohol.   (Note: I am from Canada, and even though we don't use the archaic imperial system and the ounce, this expression is still valid)

Comment: Some versions of the Bible include the phrase "tens of thousands." The New International Version, for example, uses that expression a number of times, as in 1 Samuel 18:8; 21:11; and 29:5. See also Psalm 68:17 and 144:13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting in 12s is a lot older than 1000s or millions. The traditional units based on 12 and 60 go back to the Babylonians, while 1000s mostly date back to the C18 metric system.

Indians also count in lakhs (100,000) and Crore (10,000,000)

Comment: Add some references and you've got yourself an upvote.

Comment: UK currency used to have 12 pence in a shilling. (But we also had twenty shillings in a pound.)

Comment: My question was about the reason for the relative rarity of 'tens of' as opposed to 'dozens of'. This answer hints at an explanation. The 12 pence to a shilling in former British currency may also be part of the reason, plus the fact that eggs were always sold by the dozen.

Comment: @Shoe, and inches in foot and originally 12 ounces in a pound. It's mainly because it's easier to divide up 12 of something into 2,3,4,6 than it is to divide 10

Comment: Add the etymonline link which clearly says that "dozens" is Middle English. I would like to upvote this answer https://www.etymonline.com/word/dozen You might even find references of "dozaines" or other spelling variants in 15th or 16th century literature

Answer (score 13):

We don't say *tens of* unless we are referring to larger numbers (tens of thousands, tens of millions, etc.). As pre-metric as it may be, here in the U.S. we say **dozens** for quantities between ~40 to ~100, which is approximately where *tens* would be appropriate if it were used.

That said, there is nothing *wrong* with referring to "tens of" something. It just sounds funny.

**Update**

For whoever downvoted me, here is a little perspective on the NGram issue brought up by onomatomaniak:

[image: The usage of dozens of blows tens of out of the water. Seriously.]

You can clearly see that when you compare *dozens of* to *tens of* for a couple of these identical constructions, the usage of dozens far outstrips tens. The only anomaly is when the noun modified is "miles," which is interesting but probably an outlier.

This illustrates the problem with Google NGrams. If you don't look at the orders of magnitude on the left, the "big jumps" can look very compelling. In fact, by comparison here the "tens of" lines, so compellingly vertical in the above graphs, vanish into flatlining insignificance.

I conclude from this graph that "tens of" is, as I say, falling out of usage, and is being supplanted by "dozens of."

Answer (score 4):

We *do* say "tens of." Or at least, I and other English speakers do. It may not be as common as *dozens of*, but it's hardly unheard of.

Here's an Ngram of three phrases I chose rather randomly. Note that all exhibit **increasing usage** in recent decades.

[image]

On second thought, I realized *tens of miles* was probably the way I've heard it used most often, so I added that in. The result:

[image]

And, not to leave the metric system out, here's that graph plus *tens of kilometers*.

[image]

Comment: Don't care what the stats say, "tens of" still sounds very strange, awkward, and unidiomatic to me.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the idea to use NGram and I played with it a bit. It revealed one thing all the answers before missed: **"Are you using British or American English?"**

The phrase "tens of" is only one half as popular as "dozens of" in American English, but it's use is the same in British English. [Check for yourselves.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tens+of%2Cdozens+of&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ctens%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btens%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTens%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdozens%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdozens%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDozens%20of%3B%2Cc0)

So I believe it is related to the use of metric system and other cultural habits. To me as a European non-native speaker "tens of" sounds perfectly fine and possibly preferable inn certain cases. Unless referring to eggs, of course, where dozen is the only and ultimate way to count them.

Comment: You need to check the results more carefully. Ngrams are very deceptive at first glance. Yes, "tens of" is commonly said but coupled with *tens of thousands*; *tens of millions*, and *several tens of metres* to name but a few.

Comment: Thanks for the note! You are right, I did not realized that. I chacked again, and you are right, the use other than "tens of thousands" is rare.

Answer (score -1):

We do say "tens". The OED:

> B. n. (With plural tens; and (less usually) possessive ten's.)
>
> A set of ten things or persons. ten of rupees, a unit of account in Indian money.
>
> OE    Rule St. Benet (Corpus Cambr.) xxii. 47   Tynum and twentigum on
>   anum inne ætgædere restan mid heora ealdrum.
>
> 1539    Bible (Great) Gen. xviii. 32,   I wil not destroye them for tens sake [1885 Bible (R.V.) for the ten's sake].
>
> 1611    Bible (A.V.) Deut. i. 15,   I‥made them‥captaines ouer tennes.
>
> 1894    Field 9 June 839/1   They came forth in their tens, for thirty-eight members turned out on the occasion of the first meet.
>
> 1895    Westm. Gaz. 4 Sept. 5/1   The revenue was better by 74,000 tens of rupees.
>
> 1897    C. M. Flandrau Harvard Episodes 94   One never said of Wolcott, as is said of some fellows, ‘He made the first ten of the Dicky’.

Comment: I think by *do* you mean *did*. The usage has pretty much died out. Also, the 1897 citation is not plural and does not have the same meaning.

Comment: It hasn't died out, see onomatomaniak's answer

Comment: And most of the others are translations of Hebrew or Hindu usages

Comment: Do you mean a translation of Hindi? How do you know that the fifth citation is a translation of Hindi? It's from the Westminster Gazette.

Comment: @morphail: It pretty much has died out. See my answer.

Comment: @morphail - sorry typo. I meant that by saying 74,000 * tens they were translating a local usage where you count in 10,000s or 100,000s

Comment: It might be Indian English. But it was in the Westminster Gazette, so it might not be.