# Why does 'threescore' mean sixty?

Tags: etymology

I wonder why *threescore* means sixty. I only found it means three times twenty, the math is correct, yet what link between twenty and "score" ?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. For the basic etymology of *score*, you can check the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://etymonline.com/index.php?search=score). Also see *[“Scores” = high amount?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125550)*.

Comment: In Danish and French we still count in multiple of 20. 60 in Danish is 3*20 and 50 is 2.5*20

Comment: As myself a French, I have knowledge of it, 80 is said 4 times 20, but not 4 times "score".

Comment: If you're a non-English speaker you may not have heard the word "score" which means twenty, but it's the second word of one of the top-ten famous speeches of modern English. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettysburg_Address Every single USA person would know "score" because of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Score simply *means* 20. The link is the same as between "table" and the thing I put my dinner plate on.

Now, as to how this came to be, [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=score&searchmode=none) has this to say (emphasis mine):

> score (n.) Look up score at Dictionary.com
>   late Old English scoru "twenty," from Old Norse skor "mark, notch, incision; a rift in rock," also, in Icelandic, "twenty," from Proto-Germanic *skura-, from PIE root *(s)ker- (1) "to cut" (see shear). 
>   
>   The connecting notion probably is **counting large numbers (of sheep, etc.) with a notch in a stick for each 20.** That way of counting, called vigesimalism, also exists in French: In Old French, "twenty" (vint) or a multiple of it could be used as a base, as in vint et doze ("32"), dous vinz et diz ("50"). Vigesimalism was or is a feature of Welsh, Irish, Gaelic and Breton (as well as non-IE Basque), and it is speculated that the English and the French picked it up from the Celts. Compare tally (n.).

So it's most likely a word that was used to indicate (multiples of) twenty units.

Even in modern science there is a non-decimal SI unit of quantity that equals roughly 6.022×10<sup>23</sup> units. It's called a *mole*.

I find it interesting that you got stuck on *three score* as the use of *score* that I thought of first, and I think may be one of the most famous uses is in the [Gettysburg address](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.abrahamlincolnonline.org%2Flincoln%2Fspeeches%2Fgettysburg.htm&ei=XDL3U_-fGoXN7AaY4YC4BQ&usg=AFQjCNFYzAxjHOMmKtW80UL_xDZ4eFArLQ&sig2=GZtmhlTMJwBVXPZrW3DYxQ&bvm=bv.73373277,d.ZGU)

But there it is, of course, *four* score and seven years.

Comment: thanks for your answer. For your curiosity, I got stuck on it reading the bible => revelations 13:18, searching for references on Iron maiden's "the number of the beast". About the number of Avogadro, I don't understand what it has to do here ? it's the exact integer number of atoms of carbon needed to have 12g of it ... Both it's origin and reason to exist are clear and aren't related to how a language works and changes with time.

Comment: Ah the bible. I should have known (recognized) it :) The reference to Avogadro is because _mole_ = 6,022x10^23 _items_, just like _score_ means 20 _items_. _dozen_ is another example for 12 _items_.

Comment: *Quatre-vingt* (*fourscore*) is still the way one says *eighty* in French (and counting upwards of sixty is done by twenties — seventy is *sixty-ten* and ninety is *fourscore-ten*), and sheep-scoring numbers are still used both for sheep-scoring (counting the flock) and in children's games in parts of English Britain (areas where the original Celtic languages have not merely been marginalized, but displaced altogether).

Comment: I agree mole represents a number of items just like scores, yet mole is just shorten for "molecular weight"(the actual origin is from German "Molekulargewicht"). I was troubled by the choice of "mole" as an example because there is not one but plenty of non-decimal SI units used in modern science.

Comment: Sorry for bringing it  up. If you have any other SI units _that represent items_, be my guest. Wherever mole was derived from, it is now the actual SI unit, not a shortened form of anything any more. So I thought it was a nice example of something very similar to _score_. With its own etymology, like most words.

Comment: a second is 9 192 631 770 periods of radiation between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the caesium 133 atom.

Comment: You probably find this example ridiculous. It is. My point is : mole isn't a quantity, it's a unit, avogadro's number is a quantity. The trick is : mole is the unit of quantities.

Comment: I'd like to thank you again for your answer which was exactly what I was looking for. No hard feelings about this "mole" debate ?

Comment: And did the Irish, Scots, Gauls, and Welsh pick it up from the pre-Celtic Basque-speaking inhabitants of Europe?

Comment: @AkuOni119 — Don't worry about it :-)

Answer (score 0):

One relatively obscure meaning of the word "score" is twenty.  [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=score)

Comment: Obscure?  *Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth, on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.*