# Another word for "tens" other than "dozens"

Tags: connotation, synonyms

I'm seeking another word for "tens" when describing multiples of something fewer than one-hundred.

For example:

> The landlord received *tens* of applications for the rental home.

I don't like the word "dozens" as a substitute simply because it breaks the convention of using base ten figures elsewhere:

> The landlord received *hundreds* of phone calls about the rental home.
>   The landlord noticed *thousands* of online views of the rental home listing.
>   To the landlord, it feels like he has contacted *tens of thousands* of people.

But using "dozens" carries a hefty weight with it, that "tens" seems to lack.

Is there a way to use "tens" in this context while still conveying the idea of "several" as opposed to "only a few"?

Comment: *Scores* means twenties.

Comment: @deadrat That is a legitimate answer. Post it and get some up votes ;)

Comment: It's already been posted in the dupe. ;) Tens is used; scores carries more weight, obviously. But that falsely divides into groups of twenty.

Comment: Also see *[“Scores” = high amount?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125550)*

Comment: @medica Note that the selected answer there suggests the use of "dozens", but there are other useful answers to consider. FWIW, I did use the site search before posting this and did not come across that post.

Comment: @gfullam - The top answer addresses *scores* as well. Not a problem; lots of people post dupes. :-)

Comment: @medica You're right, and I missed it. I don't disagree that this is a dupe. I regret that I couldn't find the answer using the site search.